# Traefik with LetsEncrypt wildcard and Dyn DNS

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik

I am trying to setup traefik with a wildcard certificate from LetsEncrypt.

While using the dyn provider for LetsEncrypt in Traefik I get the error message below:

```
reverse-proxy_1  | time="2018-05-01T20:19:12Z" level=debug msg="Building ACME client..."
reverse-proxy_1  | time="2018-05-01T20:19:12Z" level=debug msg="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
reverse-proxy_1  | time="2018-05-01T20:19:12Z" level=info msg=Register...
reverse-proxy_1  | time="2018-05-01T20:19:13Z" level=debug msg="Using DNS Challenge provider: dyn"
reverse-proxy_1  | time="2018-05-01T20:19:13Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"'*.lb.ops.example.net'\" : domains ['*.lb.ops.example.net'] generate certificate with no value: {    [] [] [] []}"
```

When I look at the acme.json that is generated I see this:

```
{
  "Account": {
    "Email": "my.name@example.com",
    "Registration": {
      "body": {
        "status": "valid",
        "contact": [
          "mailto:my.name@example.com"
        ]
      },
      "uri": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/34263018"
    },
    "PrivateKey": "MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAsvImYVFqq [trimmed info] BPLMwF7E1F2GJg61qYJ4a0="
  },
  "Certificates": null,
  "HTTPChallenges": null
}
```

I am using the following in my docker-compose.yml:

```
  reverse-proxy:
    command:
    - --debug
    - --logLevel=DEBUG
    - --acme.dnschallenge=true
    - --acme.dnschallenge.provider=dyn
    - --acme.domains='*.lb.ops.example.net'
    - --acme.email=my.name@example.com
    - --acme.entryPoint=https
    - --acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
    - --defaultentrypoints=http,https
    - --entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https
    - --entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS
    - --web
    depends_on:
    - consul
    environment:
      DYN_CUSTOMER_NAME: mycompanyname
      DYN_PASSWORD: a-reasonable-password
      DYN_USER_NAME: aserviceaccountname
    image: traefik:1.6
    links:
    - consul
    ports:
    - published: 80
      target: 80
    - published: 443
      target: 443
    - published: 8080
      target: 8080
    volumes:
    - /tmp/acme:/etc/traefik/acme:rw
    - /tmp/traefik:/var/log/traefik:rw
```